# What is the symbol in Maris the Chojo's hair?

Tags: symbolism, maris-the-chojo

From [Maris the Chojo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maris_the_Chojo):

[image]

What is this symbol in her hair and what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the currency symbol for the [Yen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen), the Japanese currency.

The Wikipedia article you have linked to in your question has this to say:

> Maris' obsession with money is demonstrated by her hair ornaments, in the shape of the symbol for Yen (Japanese money).

Comment: ah >_< missed that I posted answer in question. Thank you